# Horizontally and vertically centered multi-lined cells

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, cell

I want a table where the cells contain either a single line of text or two lines of text, and the cell contents are both horizontally and vertically centered.

The height of the cells should be 2cms and length 3cms (assuming the text does not overflows), and some of the cell boundaries should be bold.

One example is as follows:

[image]

Any help to create such a table in latex would be much appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: search for \mbox

Comment: @Surb I can't think of any way `\mbox` would help with this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways, depending on whether you have fixed width cells or not:

- for a standard cell (column specifier `r, l` or `c`), you can use the `makecell` command,
- for a fixed width cell, use the `m{some length}` column type

A demo of both:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}

\renewcommand\theadalign{cb}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}

\begin{document}

 \sffamily
    \begin{tabular}{ | c | c !{\vrule width2.5pt}}
    \hline
\makecell{multi-lined \\ contents} & single line \\
    \Xhline{2.5pt}
    \end{tabular}
    %
    \qquad
    %
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}m{20mm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{20mm} !{\vrule width2.5pt}}
    \hline
 multi-lined \newline contents & single line \\
    \Xhline{2.5pt}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am wondering if the space between the two lines 'multi-lined' and 'contents' can be reduced? Also, if I increase the height of the cell for the first option, like `\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[10pt]}`, both the lines move far apart, can this be reduced? And in the second option, if I increase the height by `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{20pt}`  the lines are placed towards the bottom of the cell instead of the center.

Comment: Actuallt `\cellgape` *adds* this amount of vertical space  at the top and bottom of cells, so this is the normal behaviour . Another solution, valid for both methods, use the `cellspace` package which ensures a *minimal* vertical spacing at top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you also load `siunitx`). For instance, here, you might use as tables preambles `{|Sc|Sc!{\vrule width 2.5pt}` and `{|>{\centering}S{m{20mm}}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}S{m{20mm} }!{\vrule width2.5pt}}` respectively.